# Unable to start dovecot

Tags: dovecot

I am configuring my ubuntu server for mail use so I installed dovecot all required protocols but when I start dovecot I get the following error :

```
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf: service(managesieve-login): executable is empty
```

The only thing I did after running apt-get install is I added to the conf the following lines :

```
protocols = pop3 imap

mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
```

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well based on the error it sounds like you've enabled some [`sieve`](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve) features somewhere in your configuration.  It's a handy tool, but it does have it's own independent install:

**To add sieve to dovecot:**

```
apt-get install dovecot-sieve dovecot-managesieved
```

Alternatively, probably in the `protocol lmtp` section (on my server this is in the `conf.d/20-lmtp.conf` file) you'll find the word `sieve` listed on the mail_plugins line, you could just remove this to allow dovecot to start without.